# Language package in magento2 not reflected

Tags: magento2, language

I have already created language package for fr_FR language and it's working fine. I want to add another text in that French language so I have added my text in that file and I compiled this command it running successfully, but that translated text is not coming please tell me how to add it.

```
php bin/magento i18n:pack app/i18n/Test/fr_FR/fr_FR.csv -d fr_FR
Successfully saved fr_FR language package.
```